# Excel VBA Range(Cell).Value=sum 1004:Application-Defined Or Object-Defined

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

```
Function ChangeColVal(ByVal Rng As Range, ByVal ValueToChange As Integer)
    Dim Cell1, Cell2 As String
    Dim PosOfColon, TotalCell, Sum As Integer
    PosOfColon = InStr(1, Rng.Address, ":")
    Cell1 = Left(Rng.Address, PosOfColon - 1)
    Cell2 = Right(Rng.Address, Len(Rng.Address) - PosOfColon)
    If Left(Cell1, 2) = Left(Cell2, 2) Then
        TotalCell = Rng.Count
        For i = 0 To TotalCell
            If IsNumeric(Range(Cell1).Offset(i, 0).Value) = False Then
                GoTo 112:
            End If
            Cell2 = Range(Cell1).Offset(i, 0).Address
            Sum = Range(Cell2).Cells.Value + ValueToChange
            On Error GoTo 111
            'Here getting error...
            Range(Cell2).Value = Sum
            GoTo 112
111:
            MsgBox (Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description)
112:
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox ("Select Column only...")
    End If
End Function
```

I wants to increase or decrease cell value of selected range.
I am getting error in line `Range(Cell2).Value = Sum`

**Edit**
thanx for reply, in line Range(Cell2).Value = Sum, Cell2 is pointing to cell address like $E$6.
[image: a]

If there is any option other than that pls let me know

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your function itself. Since you are executing all your Range functions on the activesheet make sure your active sheet is the one you want to use. One more thing - check the parameters you are passing to your function because they may be causing errors somehow - ie. Change the Integer to a Long/Double type. And declare `i` to be able to use it in the for loop. I am not sure what else could be causing the error to pop up :/

Comment: As 'ValueToChange' is used to hold small vaslue like 0-1000 i used it to declare as 'Integer'.
I also checked it by changing to Long but still getting same error.

Comment: @MihirPatel: What is the UDF trying to achieve? Purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok Mihir. You cannot use a UDF (User Defined Function) to modify other cells then the one the formula is used in. However, there is a workaround it by calling your function from a sub. I will show you how to do it.

Open a new workbook and make your spreadsheet look like the picture below. 
Fill in some random numbers in column A of Sheet1
[image: sheet1 setup]

Then open VBE and create a new module ( Project Explorer > Insert > Module ) and paste the code from below

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeColumnValue()

   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = Selection

   Dim inp As String
   inp = InputBox("Value to change:")

   Call ChangeColVal(rng, CLng(inp))

End Sub

Private Function ChangeColVal(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal ValueToChange As Long)
    Dim Cell1, Cell2 As String
    Dim PosOfColon, TotalCell, Sum As Long
    PosOfColon = InStr(1, rng.Address, ":")
    Cell1 = Left(rng.Address, PosOfColon - 1)
    Cell2 = Right(rng.Address, Len(rng.Address) - PosOfColon)
    If Left(Cell1, 2) = Left(Cell2, 2) Then
        TotalCell = rng.Count
        Dim i&
        For i = 0 To TotalCell - 1
            If Not IsNumeric(Range(Cell1).Offset(i, 0).Value) Then
                GoTo 112:
            End If
            Cell2 = Range(Cell1).Offset(i, 0).Address
            Sum = Range(Cell2).Cells.Value + ValueToChange
            On Error GoTo 111
            Range(Cell2).Value = Sum
            GoTo 112
111:
            MsgBox (Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description)
112:
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox ("Select Column only...")
    End If
End Function
```

Then, go back to your spreadsheet and select your range with your mouse like this:
[image: select range with mouse]
Ok, now hit `ALT + F8` to `View Macros` and run the `ChangeColumnValue` macro. 

[image: select macro]


You will be prompt for a Value to Change and all cells within selected range will be Increased/Decreased by that Value. 
[image: prompt value to change]

and your final result if you type `5` in the prompt box will look like this 
[image: result]

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

finally here is the solution.

```
Sub ChangeRowValues()

Dim rng As Range
Dim R As Range
Dim ValueToChange As Long
Dim Cell1, Cell2 As String
Dim PosOfColon, TotalCell, Sums, i As Integer
Set rng = Selection
ValueToChange = Val(InputBox("Enter Number to Change:", "Enter Number...", 0))
PosOfColon = InStr(1, rng.Address, ":")
Cell1 = Left(rng.Address, PosOfColon - 1)
Cell2 = Right(rng.Address, Len(rng.Address) - PosOfColon)
If UCase(Left(Cell1, 1)) = UCase(Left(Cell2, 1)) Then
    TotalCell = rng.Count
    For i = 0 To TotalCell - 1
        'To Chnage Values of Row....
        Range(Cell1).Offset(0, i).Select

        'To Chnage Values of Colum....
        'Range(Cell1).Offset(i,0).Select

        If IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Value) = True Then
            ActiveCell.Value = Val(ActiveCell.Value) + ValueToChange
        End If
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox ("Select Row only...")
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score -1):

range() function input is cell address, for example, range(a1:b2;g1:h4), you cannot input some result in it.

Comment: what? he is inputing the address of cell2. i see nothing wrong with it